# Excel VBA - automatic if Cell A equals X then copy and paste in Cell B

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I currently have the below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2,B11,D11")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each C In Target
            If Not Intersect(C, Range("B2,B11,D11")) Is Nothing And Not C.HasFormula Then _
                C.Value = UCase(C.Value)
        Next C
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I need to add another macro to basically do:

If G6 = N/A then copy and paste into H6, otherwise do nothing.

How should I add this in?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I'm not sure how you want to include this in your code, also your code opens an if statement inside your for loop but closes it outside, I doubt this is correct.. anyway here is the code to copy the data to H6:

```
If (ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Value = "N/A") Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("H6").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Value
Else
    'do nothing     
End If
```

Comment: OK, I have had a re think and this does what i want:Sub Uppercase()
   ' Loop to cycle through each cell in the specified range.
   For Each x In Range("A1")
      ' Change the text in the range to uppercase letters.
      x.Value = UCase(x.Value)
   Next
   If (ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Value = "N/A") Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("H6").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Value
Else
    'do nothing
End If
End Sub
However this isn't automatic, how do I make it so it is?

Comment: the code you have written effectively says this:

for each x in range("A1")

there is only one value in range A1 which is cell A1 so all this is going to do is make cell A1 uppercase

then you have if G6 is N/A then H6 = G6

its really only 2 actions.. what are you actually trying to do??